# "cordova run ubuntu" produces incomplete application

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

I'm trying to build and run a cordova project for the ubuntu platform.  The project is just the default that is produced automatically when I create a new project.  Here is the config.xml file (I added the line containing the link to the icon):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.gregory.example" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<icon src="img/logo.png" > </icon>
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

When I view the index.html file in my browser, I see the cordova logo, and a flashing button that says "CONNECTING TO DEVICE."  But when I try to run it using the CLI, it doesn't work.

Here are the commands I used:

```
gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript$ sudo cordova create example com.gregory.example Example
Creating a new cordova project.
gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript$ cd example/
gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript/example$ sudo vi config.xml 
gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript/example$ sudo cordova platform add ubuntu
Adding ubuntu project...
Running command: /home/gregory/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ubuntu/4.0.0/package/bin/create /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu com.gregory.example Example
Creating a Cordova Project:
 Project Path: /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu
 Package Name: com.gregory.example
 Project Name: Example

missing icon element in config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ubuntu

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript/example$ sudo cordova build ubuntu
Running command: /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build 
Building Desktop Application...
In order to build debian package, execute: 
cd /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu/native/com.gregory.example; debuild
gregory@gregory-1001PXD:~/javascript/example$ sudo cordova run ubuntu
Running command: /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/run 
Building Desktop Application...
In order to build debian package, execute: 
cd /home/gregory/javascript/example/platforms/ubuntu/native/com.gregory.example; debuild
Build Successful. Running the application.
Running Cordova
Launching the application.
```

But after it says "Launching the application," an empty gray window pops up, and the icon that appears in the sidebar is a question mark.  What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved when I followed someone's answer to another of my questions:

[Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887991/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable-failed-to-find-android-com)

Specifically, it was a permissions problem.  I fixed it by repeatedly running

```
cordova build ubuntu
```

*without* sudo, and then, whenever there was a permissions error, I gave my non-root user access to the relevant file or folder, e.g.

```
sudo chown -R gregory /home/gregory/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/.npmignore
```

After doing this several times, the build command eventually executed without errors, and then

```
cordova run ubuntu
```

was successful.