# Cordova run ubuntu gives a frozen window - ubuntu 15.10

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, installation, cross-compiling

Installed ubuntu using the resources :
 - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/
 - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/

everything command works until I get to the run command:
 - cordova run ubuntu 
A white window appears and with the title "cordova-ubuntu" that soon just gets stuck; like an ubuntu program -

How do I get the application to run as it should

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem:

["cordova run ubuntu" produces incomplete application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582946/cordova-run-ubuntu-produces-incomplete-application/35001932#35001932)

It turned out to be a permissions problem.  I fixed it by repeatedly running

```
cordova build ubuntu
```

*without* sudo, and then, whenever there was a permissions error, I gave my non-root user access to the relevant file or folder, e.g.

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/.npmignore
```

After doing this several times, the build command eventually executed without errors, and then

```
cordova run ubuntu
```

was successful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Gregory ... I haven't been on this for a while ... But pnce I get back on it - I'll look it over ... Thanks

Comment: thanks man, this helped ... but the better solution was moving on to the newer versions of the all the involved apis .. aswell as the nrew linux distro .. things are just cleaned up a bit better there ... thanks man :)